# Sending email through telnet SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

After I connect to one of gmail's SMTP servers (via windows cmd), when I try

```
sending mail to myself, it keeps giving me the same error.

220 mx.google.com ESMTP u3si16129057wmg.22 - gsmtp
ehlo b
250-mx.google.com at your service, [2607:fcd8:a:5:426d:e920:51f3:f36e]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
MAIL FROM: <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK u3si16129057wmg.22 - gsmtp
RCPT TO: <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK u3si16129057wmg.22 - gsmtp
DATA
354  Go ahead u3si16129057wmg.22 - gsmtp
SOMETHING SOMETHING SOMETHING.

.
550-5.7.1 [2607:fcd8:a:5:426d:e920:51f3:f36e      11] Our system has detected
550-5.7.1 that this message is not RFC 5322 compliant. To reduce the amount of
550-5.7.1 spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please review
550 5.7.1  RFC 5322 specifications for more information. u3si16129057wmg.22 - gs
mtp


Connection to host lost.

Press any key to continue...
```

I looked up RFC 5322 and tried the following

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP bo10si34007895wjb.163 - gsmtp
ehlo b
250-mx.google.com at your service, [2607:fcd8:a:5:426d:e920:51f3:f36e]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
MAIL FROM: <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com> CRLF
250 2.1.0 OK bo10si34007895wjb.163 - gsmtp
RCPT TO: <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com> CRLF
250 2.1.5 OK bo10si34007895wjb.163 - gsmtp
DATA CRLF
354  Go ahead bo10si34007895wjb.163 - gsmtp
something something something. CRLF
. crlf
. CRLF
.
550-5.7.1 [2607:fcd8:a:5:426d:e920:51f3:f36e      11] Our system has detected
550-5.7.1 that this message is not RFC 5322 compliant. To reduce the amount of
550-5.7.1 spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please review
550 5.7.1  RFC 5322 specifications for more information. bo10si34007895wjb.163 -
 gsmtp


Connection to host lost.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the question/issue you are trying to address?

Comment: How do I write an RFC 5322 compliant email through telnet?

Answer (score 4):

I can only guess at the OP's reason, but as a sysadmin in a hosting company I use it all the time to debug mail problems.  The procedure is simple and described many places, for example https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2010/02/17/manually-testing-smtp-mail-issues-via-telnet.

The problem is that Google is interpreting RFC 5322 somewhat liberally, to require an additional "From:" field after data, such as:

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 25
Trying 173.194.222.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (173.194.222.27).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP j6si1491418lja.259 - gsmtp
HELO yourhost.com
250 mx.google.com at your service
mail from: <me@myemail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK j6si1491418lja.259 - gsmtp
rcpt to: <some.guy@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK j6si1491418lja.259 - gsmtp
data
354  Go ahead j6si1491418lja.259 - gsmtp
From: me@myemail.com
Subject: test, please ignore
test, please ignore
.
250 2.0.0 OK  1571305610 j6si1491418lja.259 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection j6si1491418lja.259 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `DATA` command a properly formatted email message is expected/required.

[RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) defines the standard that defines how a *"properly formatted message"* should look.

> A message consists of header fields (collectively called "the header
> section of the message") followed, optionally, by a body.  The header
> section is a sequence of lines of characters with special syntax as
> defined in this specification.
> The body is simply a sequence of
> characters that follows the header section and is separated from the
> header section by an empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding
> the CRLF).

As a quick and easy shortcut to get such a message: most email clients allow you to view the raw/original message format of an existing email. Copy and paste that.